# Qt Mac: Utilize all window width.

Tags: qt

Is there some forced windows margin of two pixels on Qt/Mac?

No matter how much I try, I can't draw or put widgets on the edge of the widget.

Look at this screenshot from Mac's Messages app:

[image]

As you can see, the highlight goes all the way to the edge of the window.

I cannot reproduce this in Qt. No matter what I do, I will always have a 2-pixel invisible "margin" that comes from no where and although my *.UI file has a widget that has sub-widgets stretched to its very edges -- when the UI becomes a live widget -- it'll have those margins.

Where is this coming from? It's not in the stylesheet file.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the culprit. It's Qt-Creator !

Turns out, none of the changes for the *.UI form got built. so my cancellation of the margins, although visible on the UI form, were never compiled. the ui_*. file was never re-generated.I had to manually delete it for things to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a simple test (Qt 5.2.1) with a line edit inside a `Widget` with `Horizontal Layout` with 0 margins and I have all the width used.[image]